# Webview zoom functionality not stable after refresh activity

Tags: android, webview

In my activity all content are manage in webview with all web settings.
    and my activity content is refresh every 1 second. So when I am trying to 
    zoom  webview. every second webview maintaing its original position.

> I want to maintain zoom state in webview. and this happens only in
>   version 4.0.3.
>
> ```
> my webview is in Timer function . and all settings of webview are below .which 
> outside of Timer function :
> ```

```
 web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

Please help me. If anyone knows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use these function:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#getDefaultZoom()

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDefaultZoom(android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity)

You'll be able to read the zoom level before refreshing, and set it again after the refresh if finished?